# Is this the correct syntax to check for radio OR checkbox select?

Tags: jquery

I have a quiz plugin and I've added a div to display specific messages if someone presses the VOTE button before selecting an answer. Once they actually choose an answer I wanted to make the error message div fade back out, so included at the end

```
jQuery('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {     
jQuery('#error-messages').fadeOut();
});
```

Now I just realized that some of the multiple choice questions use checkboxes instead, so I changed the first line of the code to

```
jQuery('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio "]').click(function() {
```

It works, but is that the right way to do it?

Comment: This applies a `click` event listener to all checkboxes and radio buttons. Sounds like it's exactly what you want!

Comment: that's how you list multiple "separate" selector strings. `$('a,b')` is logically `$('a') or $('b')`, pseudo-codewise

Comment: Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the simplified form as below:

```
$('input:radio,input:checkbox')
```

Comment: Plus 1 this could be the answer, a shorter way. Also as alternative `$(':radio,:checkbox')` https://jsfiddle.net/vks5g51m/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the most succinct way of selecting multiple types of input fields. There's no way to make that any simpler unless you start getting into using classes on your form elements.

Comment: Great thanks! I did look at classes but the plugin uses IDs for the answers, and I didn't want to change it too much. Thanks again!